# Qual o ordenamento (ordem) padrão do resultado de uma consulta SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma tabela chamada "aluno" no banco de dados, e sua colunas sejam `nome`, `matricula` e `curso`, sendo sua chave primária a coluna `matricula`. A coluna `matricula` não tem auto_increment e um número de matrícula maior não significa, necessariamente, que foi inserido após um número de matrícula menor. Exemplo: a matrícula 201033 foi inserida após 201941. Se eu rodo o  comando:

`SELECT * FROM aluno;`

sei que todos os registros são retornados, mas a primeira linha retornada é a linha que foi inserida primeiro e a última retornada é a última que foi inserida? **Qual a ordem padrão do resultado da consulta?** Neste caso específico, seria possível ordenar a consulta por ordem de inserção, já que não tenho um campo na tabela que representa a ordem em que as linhas (tuplas) foram inseridas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O padrão `SQL` não garante que os dados recuperados tenham uma ordenação padrão. Sem um `ORDER BY` específico, a ordenação dos seus resultados será sempre **indeterminada**.

No `MySQL`, a ordem das colunas que não fazem parte da cláusula `ORDER BY` é determinada pela maneira como o `planner/optimizer` decidiu criar o conjunto de resultados a ser retornado.

Consultas simples como `SELECT * FROM tabela` provavelmente serão retornadas na mesma ordem em que foram armazenadas no disco, e podem estar ordenadas pela chave primária, pela ordem em que foram inseridas ou em uma outra ordem aleatória qualquer.

A regra é: **NUNCA** confie na ordem *padrão*, ela pode mudar da noite para o dia! Use **sempre** a cláusula `ORDER BY` se a ordenação dos dados é importante pra você.

**Referências:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by

Answer (score 2):

O resultado aparecerá na ordem **que vier**, dependendo das operações que fizer na tabela, a ordem pode não ser a mesma da ordem de inserção.

Para garantir que os registros virão na ordem de inserção é necessário ter um campo com `AUTO INCREMENT`.

Uma analogia é o conceito de conjunto na matemática (SET ou BAG). Em conjuntos, a ordem dos elementos é irrelevante. Por isso existe o conceito de conjunto ordenado: cada elemento do conjunto é um par ordenado contendo um inteiro e o elemento em sí. E a ordem é estabelecida pela ordem do número inteiro. O `AUTO INCREMENT` ou `SEQUENCE`, no caso do banco, estabelece a relação de ordem.

---

De fato a ordem não é indeterminada, é deterministica. Porém, em alguns casos, seria necessário um super computador para prever o resultado da query. Para efeitos práticos é considerada indeterminada.

Esse fenômeno se chama caos determinístico.

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_do_caos

> Pequenas diferenças nas condições iniciais (tais como as causadas por erros de arredondamento em computação numérica) produzem resultados amplamente divergentes para tais sistemas dinâmicos, tornando a previsão a longo prazo impossível, em geral.[2] Isso acontece apesar de estes sistemas serem deterministas, o que significa que seu comportamento futuro é totalmente determinado por suas condições iniciais, sem elementos aleatórios envolvidos.[3] Em outras palavras, a natureza determinista desses sistemas não os torna previsíveis.[4][5] Este comportamento é conhecido como caos determinístico, ou simplesmente caos.

Comment: *"aparecerá na ordem física da tabela"* isso não é certeza, vai depender do otimizador da quey. Se o otimizar escolher algum índice para executar a query, esse índice pode mudar a ordem do resultado, que pode não ser a "ordem física". Como foi pontuado na outra resposta, podemos dizer que a ordem é "indeterminada"

Comment: Sim, sim, e também pode vir na ordem em que está no cache.

Comment: Editei a resposta.